# how can i use a Jbutton in a class to trigger a panelSlider effect which is in a button actionPerformed in another class

Tags: java

how can i use a Jbutton in a class to trigger a panelSlider effect which is in a button actionPerformed in another class

[Find the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOMSl.jpg)

```
public class programDisplay extends javax.swing.JPanel { /** * Creates new form programDisplay */
    public programDisplay() {
      initComponents();
    }
```

Comment: can you add more code pls? Where is the `programDisplay()` constructor  you are using in the `ProgramMenu`? And where do you instantiate the buttons and the `jpanel`?

Comment: public class programDisplay extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form programDisplay
     */
    public programDisplay() {
        initComponents();
    }

Comment: am struggling to paste the code so i took a screenshot as image above thanx

Comment: mhh thats also just a snippet. just copy the code into your question, select the code and press Ctrl + K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example for sliding effect of panel. you can take it as a reference and implement your requirement.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SlidingPanel {

    JPanel panel;

    public void makeUI() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
                new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        panel.setLocation(panel.getX() - 1, 0);
                        if (panel.getX() + panel.getWidth() == 0) {
                            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                            System.out.println("Timer stopped");
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sliding Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SlidingPanel().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** :

in HomePane.java

```
rightPane rPane = new rightPane();
JPanel lPane = new leftPane(rPane);
```

in leftPane.java

```
private rightPane rPane;
public leftPane(final rightPane rPane)
    {
        pane = new JPanel();
        this.rPane = rPane;
        staffLogin = new JButton("STAFF LOGIN");
        adminLogin = new JButton("ADMIN LOGIN");
        guestLogin = new JButton("GUEST LOGIN");

        staffLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                rPane.trigerEvent();
            }
        });

        this.setLayout(null);

        this.add(staffLogin);
        this.add(adminLogin);
        this.add(guestLogin);

        staffLogin.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        adminLogin.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        guestLogin.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));

        staffLogin.setBounds(20, 10, 200, 50);
        adminLogin.setBounds(20, 75, 200, 50);
        guestLogin.setBounds(20, 140, 200, 50);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    }
```

Comment: thanx so much i used your slider code but am still failing to achieve what i wanna do

Comment: explain your requirement clearly possibly with images if I can help.

Comment: i added a link i upload the video shot of the entire program ...thanx so much...Dipali  http://www.4shared.com/video/-__BfbW1ce/javaProblem.html

Comment: add the screenshots to question

Comment: am having 3 classes according to the video ..one is homepane.java, leftpane.java and rightPane.java...so when i click the Admin Login button in the leftpane....it should trigger the button one the rightpane to slide the pane in the same rightpane

Comment: i've been struggling for the past 1hour to paste all the 3 java class code... plz can you check them out here http://textuploader.com/5vyk6